# assignin sockaddr to another changes the addr?

Tags: c++, sockets, copy, winsock, variable-assignment

While trying the following the address in the second sockaddr changes:

```
/*Stuff*/
sockaddr add1, add2;
recvfrom(/*socket*/, /*buffer*/, /*count*/, /*flag*/, &add1, /*fromlen*/);

add2 = add1; //The sa_data - part changes O_o...

/*Stuff*/
```

Anyone knows why?...

**EDIT: 1.I changed the sockaddr to sockaddr_storage which definetly has enough space for sockaddr_in!!
2. I memset the structure to zero on initialization
3. I wrote a copy ruitine for my copy/assignment wishes:**

```
memcpy(&AddrTarget, &AddrSource, sizeof(sockaddr_storage));
```

**But this does not help, too!... Im desperate:(...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is `fromlen` being set when you call `recvfrom()`? If `fromlen > sizeof(add1)`, you are possibly writing over `add2` by accident.

[Beej's Guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/syscalls.html#sendtorecv) suggests that you use local variables of type `struct sockaddr_storage`, which is guaranteed to be big enough to hold any of the `struct sockaddr_foo`s in use.

Comment: Didn't know about this, very nice.

Comment: Yes... I did use this, but: It still does not work... what I am doing is:

SOCKADDR_STORAGE x, y;
recvfrom(/*recv addr into x*/);
y= x; <<---- still changes the content...

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the whole struct isn't being copied. sa_data can be longer than 14 elements. But doing a copy misses the bits after the 14'th value.

http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_305.html

Comment: Would it be a solution to use the SOCKADDR_STORAGE structure instead, and cast it , when needed?...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the common case of TCP - you probably want to use a sockaddr_in, which has space for the extra fields.

Comment: `recvfrom` is typically used with UDP.